# Unnecessary ScrollBars showing in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms:
Can't figure out why it is showing scoll bars in this screen shot?
I still want it to show Vertical scroll bars "as needed", but this horizontal scroll bar? Why is it showing? My items aren't that wide...

[image]

here is also some initialization I am doing on FormLoad ..if any part of that is the culprit

```
    listView.Scrollable = true;
    listView.FullRowSelect = true;
    listView.View = View.Details;
    listView.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
    ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
    header.Text = "MyHeader";
    header.Name = "MyColumn1";
    header.Width = listView.Width;
    listView.Columns.Add(header);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header.Width = listView.Width;
```

Nope, you forgot about the border.  Fix:

```
header.Width = listView.ClientSize.Width;
```

Comment: This does not help in my case. I am using something like listView.ClientSize.Width - 10. Just client size still causes horizontal scroller.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for help.  Click the Ask Question button.